# ListItemRenderer 'data' parameter

Tags: grails

I am using Listitemrenderer(Zk UI and Grails) to render a list of books from database table called "book". I have different types of books in the table. the book types are determined by the bookType attribute. The issue I am having is that when I do:
    Book bookInstance = (Book) data
      it shows null point exception when there are different types of books in the table. But in the case when there are books of a single type, it works fine.

Is there a way to filter the parameter 'data' of Listitemrenderer so that I could get books of a certain type I want? Again, there is an attribute bookType in database table that distinguishes different types of book.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please post your code as well?

Comment: http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/03/zk-itemrendered-with-listbox-example.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use Query String with 'where' clause specifying 'book_type'.
this way use can fetch the desired result.